# Why are nested properties of this TypeScript recursive function argument inferred as `unknown`?

Tags: typescript, recursion

In this example using a recursive generic type, why does typescript infer unknown for the `b` prop of the second `createFoo` call?

```
type FooConfig<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    [P in keyof T[K]]: number | ((t: Foo<T>) => number);
  };
};

type Foo<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]:{
    [P in keyof T[K]]: number;
  };
};

const createFoo = <
  T,
  TFoo = Foo<T>
>(args: FooConfig<T>): TFoo =>  {
  /// code
}

const foo = createFoo({
  a: {
    i: 1,
  },
  b: {
    ii: () => 1,
  }
});

// works as intended
console.log('@-->foo', foo.b.ii);

const foo2 = createFoo({
  a: {
    i: 1,
  },
  b: {
    ii: (f) => f.a.i += 1, // <-- added param to method, f.a.i is correctly typed here
    // iii: () => 1 // <-- if you uncomment this line, it works
  }
});

// but now there's a type error when function argument is present in config
console.log('@-->foo2', foo2.b.ii);
```

This example has two instances of the `createFoo` method. The first call is not using a function argument for the `b.ii` param and everything works as intended.

The resulting `.d.ts` of the first example looks like this:

```
declare const foo2: Foo<{
    a: {
        i: unknown;
    };
    b: {
        ii: unknown;
    };
}>;
```

Note that the system is able to infer the existence of the `b.ii` key.

In the 2nd `createFoo` call, the `b.ii` param takes a method argument that is a recursive reference to the `createFoo` method argument itself.

The resulting `.d.ts` looks like this:

```
declare const foo2: Foo<{
    a: {
        i: unknown;
    };
    b: unknown;
}>;
```

I understand why `b.ii` would be inferred as `unknown`, but the problem is that the entire `b` object is `unknown`.

Interestingly, the recursive reference type itself works as expected (i.e. the `f` in `b.ii` is typed correctly)

But in the resulting output, references to `foo2.b.ii` cause a type error.

Strangely, if I add a `b.iii` param as either a `number` or a `() => number` type (i.e. not using the recursive reference), then the system is able to infer the existence of the `b.ii` key and the `foo2.b.ii` type error is resolved.

[TypeScript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-gli1FDnK9UIooYpwD4QDYPjgLBDGFAABRcCBrOBhWaaCNg0DYMAwW8vyrVcEBVUh6xqOoEGbVxWw5WgRygbtex7EIB2I4dRzQcdVw2KokKgABqUhJ3vBcl1QD4QCgc4MDQNAdG2a5mHBYAAAsaigaSMHBO5pLgc4oBk48tx6dRtmAId72Q0iAGZp1nbioHFIo1DuHY5KkhSoA+FhoCqd9mDKR8j2vctUPvXkzW0bQDwfKTtlXCyN1QUEtOssp7LASpLRs8JvxxSsfz-ACgJA8DIOg2lYIwukEKQlDsiAA)

This example is my attempt to extract the problem from its larger codebase into its most basic elements.

As noted in the example, there are several ways to "trick" the compiler into working as expected, but because this code will be used in a library the workarounds are not ideal.

Some things that "work" but aren't acceptable solutions:

```
const foo2 = createFoo({
  a: {
    i: 1,
  },
  b: {
    ii: (f) => f.a.i += 1,
    iii: () => 1 // <-- adding another param without the method argument solves the issue
  }
});
```

```
const foo2 = createFoo({
  a: {
    i: 1,
  },
  b: {
    ii: (f: { a: { i: number }}) => f.a.i += 1, // <-- explicitly typing out the `f` param
  }
});
```

Comment: TypeScript has limitations when inferring both generic type arguments and contextual callback argument types at the same time.  There are a bunch of github issues about this, like  [ms/TS#49618](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49618).  Probably [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) is the canonical open request about this problem. TS doesn't have full unification (see [ms/TS#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134)) so these limitations are somewhat inevitable, unfortunately.

Comment: Does that fully address your question?  If so I could write up an answer with an explanation; otherwise, what am I missing?  (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: Hi @jcalz, thank you so much for this response.

So when I look at the resulting `.d.ts`, I see this:

```ts
declare const foo2: Foo<{
    a: {
        i: unknown;
    };
    b: unknown;
}>;
```

What I'm wondering is, why can't it infer the existence of the `b.ii` key? If I could get it to infer something like this it would allow me to work past the issue:

```ts
declare const foo2: Foo<{
    a: {
        i: unknown;
    };
    b: {
        ii: unknown;
    };
}>;
```

Comment: @jcalz apologies for the bad code formatting in the previous comment. I just updated the question with the same clarification.

Comment: I won't write up an answer since it seems like you're looking for something more specific. I don't know what to say specifically about your particular case, since it would involve more stepping though the compiler code than I care to do.  The general issue is ms/TS#47599; for more specifics maybe someone else will come along who has more time/insight.  Good luck!